# How can I resolve System.InvalidOperationException when I use databind on my dropdownlist in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have an issue I need to refresh an `asp:dropdownlist` but when I do `DDList.DataBind()` I have this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control

**.aspx file**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_LD" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="DS_LD" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="ILD" OnDataBound="GV_LD_DataBound" OnRowDeleted="GV_LD_RowDeleted">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AbonnementAchat" HeaderText="Test" SortExpression="Qty" DataFormatString="{0:c}" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" Text="delete" CommandName="delete" />
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>

<asp:FormView ID="FV_DLD" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ILD" DataSourceID="DS_LD" DefaultMode="Insert">   
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDList" runat="server" DataSourceID="DS_TP" DataTextField="ic" DataValueField="icp" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("icp") %>' OnDataBound="DDList_DataBound"></asp:DropDownList>
</asp:FormView>
```

**.aspx.cs file**

```
protected void GV_LD_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList DDList= (DropDownList)FV_DLD.FindControl("DDList");
    DDList.DataBind();
}
```

So when I click on delete I have the error. Does someone have any idea how to resolve the error?

Comment: Why are you doing a FindControl? Is the Grid inside a FormView/DetailsView? if not than just use `DDList.DataBind()` though you don't really need to do that on a post back since it will get done as part of the post back. Whatis `FV_DLD` as it is not in the code you are showing..

Comment: @SalikRafiq FV_DLD is a formview and I have to refresh my dropdownlist cause if I remove or add something in my gridview which aleardy exist in my dropdownlist I have to add it or remove it in my dropdownlist

Comment: `FormView` has Edit/Insert/Item templates. I note that you have the FormView in `InsertMode` in this mode I think there is no record to Bind - which could be the issue, I would try rather to DataBind on the FV_OLD and see if that cure the issue.

`FormView` are notoriously fussy.